# Karabiner-Elements how to map pc style home-end keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra, karabiner

recently I'v updated to macOS sierra and found that Karabiner is not supported.
Developers have released Karabiner-Elements but it seem in a "pre-user friendly" state. I cant understand how to map home and end keys in a pc style, as in the original Karabiner. 
A user guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I just suffered through trying to get this to work as well.  What I ended up doing was following [these instructions](http://blog.evilissimo.net/mac-os-x-keyboard-bindings-for-home-and-end-keys), with a few tweaks.

Here are the steps:

1. Open TextEdit and create a new file.
2. Paste the following:

   ```
    {
    "\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
    "\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";                        
    "$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";
    "$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";
    }
   ```
3. Save to {your user folder}/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict (UTF-8 encoding)
4. Restart your computer.

I also found [this helpful utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/) that seems to be a handy editor for modifying your .dict file.  It would seem that making new key mappings should be easier with this tool.

Comment: This appears to no longer work, I can't find a keybindings folder in the specified location